# vba copy listobject table to listobject table

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

Being a bit new to VBA I have searched for code that I can combine with an attempt to solve the problem. I am building a "task tracker" that uses a Target table (TargetTbl) of tasks to display a dynamic gantt chart.  The Ttbl can be modified manually for everyday mangement of tasks and it can also get updated annually from a Source table (SourceTbl) of reoccurring tacks to reduce effort.  My aim is to is to copy the Source table (SourceTbl) to be added to the bottom of the Target table (TargetTbl) using ListObjects.
The following code errors - an error has occurred at line -1

```
Sub UPDATEpa()

'dimensioning    Source table (SourceTbl)
'                Target table (TargetTbl)
'                Target table add row to last row (TargetTblLastRow)

Dim SourceTbl As ListObject
Dim TargetTbl As ListObject
Dim TargetTblLastRow As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set SourceTbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RepeatActivities")
Set TargetTbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Activity")
Set TargetTblLastRow = Ttbl.ListRows.Add

    SourceTbl.DataBodyRange.Copy
    TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error has occured at line " & i - 1 & " or" & i, , "Error Macro"
End Sub
```

I may be going about this the wrong way.  based on other posts I have noticed that VBA needs to be written in a particular way to reduce errors from automated copy scripts.  I'm wondering if checking and copying each cell/value is needed?

Also, based on my experience of manually pasting into a table that is a ListObject, the copied in formula, even though identical, take the referencing of the source table and then imposes that on all of the existing rows in the target table.
I have found that the simple cut and paste macro doesn't reliably work for me in this case.

thanks for your help in advance,  John H

Comment: Hi John, Welcome to SO, you can always press edit below the tags of your post if you didn't finish it.

Answer (score 0):

You have miss-names a variable:

```
Set TargetTblLastRow = TargetTbl.ListRows.Add
```

not

```
Set TargetTblLastRow = Ttbl.ListRows.Add
```

Also, better to use the correct type `Dim TargetTblLastRow As ListRow`

Yet another example of why `Option Explicit` is good...

Comment: Thanks Chris,
I can blame domestic blindness on the variable miss-name and made the change (thanks), but Im not sure about what your option explicit/dim comment is about?

Comment: [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement) requires all variable to be declared (or a compile error is thrown).  It would have called out `Ttbl` as "Variable Not Defined"

Comment: I see now.  I still get a an error when I run it after your valuable attention to detail correction.  I commented out my error capture and get a "Subscript out of range"

Comment: I ran your code snippet on a sheet with containing appropriately tables, it runs file.  Check you sheet selection and table name spelling.

Comment: thanks for testing, it gives me piece of mind, I always think it will be a logic problem (nice to be wrong).  when you refer to "sheet selection" what would this look like?  I currently have a macro button on the target sheet. do I need to select the source table?

Comment: Being new to VBA I may have misunderstood the dynamic nature of ListObject tables.  Can I reference a ListObject table without referencing a worksheet?

Comment: 1) your code refers to `Activesheet` so you need to ensure that the correct sheet is active in excel (just go to Excel and select it) - but you don't _have_ to do it that way, eg you can use `Workbooks("BookByName.xlsx").Worksheets("SheetByName").ListObject("TableByName")`.  2) you _do_ need to reference the table by worksheet, see point 1.  You _don't_ need to select that actual table.  3) the table names you set in Excel need to match the table names referred to in VBA

Comment: Since you trigger the Macro from a button on the sheet with the tables, the correct sheet _should_ be active.  If you get _subscript out of range_ that suggests one or both the tables n't match the VBA code names you've used

Comment: Great Chris,  I added the Worksheets() reference as suggested and it works like clockwork.

Comment: `code    Sub UPDATEpa()    
    'dimensioning Source table (SourceTbl)
     ' Target table (TargetTbl)
     ' Target table add row to last row (TargetTblLastRow)
     Dim SourceTbl As ListObject
     Dim TargetTbl As ListObject
     Dim TargetTblLastRow As Variant
     Set SourceTbl = Worksheets("REPEAT ACTIVITIES").ListObjects("RepeatActivities")
     Set TargetTbl = Worksheets("Activity").ListObjects("Activity")
     Set TargetTblLastRow = TargetTbl.ListRows.Add SourceTbl.DataBodyRange.
    Copy TargetTblLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End Sub  `